# Application crashing while calling property selector on third party API

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I am using a third party library and randomly facing crashes while calling a method in my code.

The crashlogs says unrecognized selector viewControllers sent to .

**Crash Log:**  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ThirdPartyController viewControllers]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e959bc0'

However, if you see below, I have taken all safe handlings before calling this method. What could be wrong.

```
+ (UINavigationController *)currentNavigationController:(UINavigationController *)iPreviousNavigationController {
 UINavigationController *aCurrentNavigationController = iPreviousNavigationController;
 UINavigationController *aChildNavigationController = (UINavigationController *)[iPreviousNavigationController modalViewController];

 if (aChildNavigationController) {
aCurrentNavigationController = [self currentNavigationController:aChildNavigationController];
 } 

 return aCurrentNavigationController;
```

}

```
+ (UIViewController *)currentViewController:(UINavigationController *)iPreviousNavigationController {
    UINavigationController *aCurrentNavigationController = [self currentNavigationController:iPreviousNavigationController];

    if (!aCurrentNavigationController || ![aCurrentNavigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(viewControllers)]) {
    aCurrentNavigationController = [self applicationDelegate].navigationController;
    }

    UIViewController *aCurrentViewController;

    if ([aCurrentNavigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(viewControllers)]) {
         aCurrentViewController = [aCurrentNavigationController.viewControllers lastObject];
    }

    return aCurrentViewController;
}
```

Comment: Which 3rd party component are you using?

Comment: Does the crash log say unrecognized selector sent to "viewController" or "viewControllers"?

Comment: It is some API built by another team and they have confirmed that they do not support viewControllers method on their objects. I have edited question to put the crash log received.